# How to extract ids of the rows with minimum value in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, stored-procedures

I have the following table

```
RecordID     Group     Date        Value
----------------------------------------
 1           Test 1   1/01/2012     10
 2           Test 1   1/01/2012     10
 3           Test 1   1/01/2012     20
 4           Test 2   1/01/2012     20
 5           Test 1   2/01/2012     10
 6           Test 2   2/01/2012     30
 7           Test 1   2/01/2012     20
 8           Test 1   2/01/2012     20
 9           Test 2   2/01/2012     20
10           Test 1   3/01/2012     10
11           Test 2   3/01/2012     10
12           Test 2   3/01/2012     20
13           Test 3   3/01/2012     10
14           Test 1   4/01/2012     10
```

I need to get all RecordIds, where for the same date and same group it has the lowest value and disregard all records for the same date and group that have greater value. So my query needs to group by "date" and "group" and find records with lowest value, that is result should be:

RecordIds: 1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14

Comment: Well I can do grouping by group and date and take MIN(Value), but I cannot select IDs as it will break grouping

Comment: The code you've written that is not working??

Comment: Just a simple select statement: select min(value), group, date from MyTable group by group, date. if I add record id to select it will break grouping loogic as it will do unique group for each id

Comment: @marc_s Both 1 and 2 have the same value of 10, so both need to be included in my scenario. Mikael has already answered my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [rank](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102(v=sql.90).aspx) in a sub query.

```
select T.RecordID,
       T.[Group],
       T.Date,
       T.Value
from 
  (
    select RecordID,
           [Group],
           Date,
           Value,
           rank() over(partition by [Group], Date order by Value) as rn
    from YourTable
  ) as T
where T.rn = 1
order by T.RecordID
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4893/1/0)